# How to update mongoDB from post()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a MEAN Stack application. My post function is as follows:

```
app.post('/updateGroup/:id', function(req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id; // = mongoDB ObjectID ie: "55616e2a37e8728266ceac6"
 var vals = {};

 vals['hostName'] = req.body.hostName // = a String ie, "Steve"
                                      // this is a different name value than the
                                      // current hostName key that is in
                                      // the groupList db

 db.groupList.update(
    {"_id": id},
    {$set : vals},
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    }
 );
});
```

When I access this function in my front-end Angular code my

```
console.log(result);
```

Comes out as:

```
{ ok: true, n: 0, updatedExisting: true }
```

But I should see n: 1 to indicate there was an update? Why is my Node application not updating my mongoDB key:value pair?

Is there something about db.collection.update() that I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of mongo are you using?

Comment: On an update, the writeresult is returned, I would start by investigating that: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out:

When assigning the _id query I needed to do it like this:

```
id['_id'] = mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id);
```